# $.when and score of "this"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope

I am using backbone and doing the following:

```
var self = this;
$.when(commentCollections.fetch()).done(function(comments){
  self.comments = comments;
  console.log(self.comments);
}).fail(function(){
  console.log('Could not fetch comments.');
});

console.log(this.comments);
```

As you can see I am trying to keep the reference of "this" in tack. `self.comments` refers to a "class level variable" set to `[]`.

When I run this I get:

```
[]
Object {comments: Array[6]}
```

in the console. the `[]` refers to `this.comments` and the the `Object ...` refers to `self.comments` One might say, well do everything inside the `.done()` but I need, for other reason, this, what I am trying to do, concept to work.

Why is the scope of "this" not being preserved?

Comment: callbacks are tricky of what `this` is.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `this`. Your code is **asynchronous**. `console.log(this.comments)` is executed **before** the promise is resolved, i.e. before `this.comments` is populated and the other `console.log` call is executed.

Comment: i removed the close vote.

Comment: *"but I need, for other reason, this, what I am trying to do, concept to work."* if you mean accessing the values before they exist, that's simply not possible. `this.comments` will have the values you want, just not at the moment you currently trying to access them.

Comment: How do I "wait" for them to exist? and then carry on?

Comment: By putting the code that needs the data in or call it from the `done` callback. Or, since this seems to be some kind of "class", instead of loading the data inside the constructor, pass the data as dependency to the constructor.